# Asus and Windows 7 home edition hot keys

Tags: shortcuts, hotkeys, autohotkey

I have an ASUS Windows 7 home edition that has hot keys or short cuts turned on that make typing on the computer almost impossible.  How do I turn of these extra keyboard short cuts or features?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean?  What hotkeys?  Usually you have to hit the Fn key or something...

Comment: I am not hitting a Fn key, but typing and find data automatically deleted or other options I did not intend.  It appears to have some type of quick keys embedded when purchased.  Both ASUS computers new, different models, 64 bit, Windows 7 home edition.  This is not a virus, but a feature that appears to be turned on, hope this helps.

Comment: I've never used an ASUS branded machine but I can't think they'd be stupid enough to have key SEQUENCES of just letters and things bound to hotkeys.  You must be hitting some kind of modifiers keys...or I'm going nuts.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure it is a combination of Shift key and something else, really a problem thanks.  On the internet I find a number of complaints about Windows 7 Short cuts/hot keys /mouse functions but not help. Apprecaite the effort.

Comment: Found a note elsewhere, that suggested turning the mouse pad sensitivity down, that my palm may be toudhing the pad.  It seems to work better now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows registry for the AppKey key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey

Rename the AppKey key to something like AppKeyX to disable all the app keys, or just rename the numbered subkeys you wish to disable

.
[image]

Also check to see what is in

HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\MobilePc\HotStartButtons

Rename HotStartButtons or the numbered subkeys you wish to disable.

.
[image]

This may not disable all the hotkeys but should get most of them.

Make notes of this so you can re enable them later if you need to.

.